# Imageview not on correct row after scrolling in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview, android-viewholder

I have an app that displays my e-mail via microsoft graph api.
Everything but 1 things i working fine so far. When the list first loads in, all info is correctly displayed, but when i scroll down, then back up. The imageview of the attachement sits on the wrong rows. It just displays on rows without attachement. In the adapter i have an if clausule which says to only show the image in the row if the hasAttachement value is "true".. I really don't get why it is redrawin the image in the wrongs rows..

The method where i set the attachement is called:
setBijlage() in MessagesAdapter

EDIT: If i click the row in my app, that row displays correctly again (gains an icon if it has attachement, and deletes it if it doesn't)

MailActivity.java

```
public class MailActivity extends AppCompatActivityRest implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener, MessagesAdapter.MessageAdapterListener {

    private String currentFolder;
    private String currentUser;
    private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private MessagesAdapter mAdapter;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private ActionModeCallback actionModeCallback;
    private ActionMode actionMode;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mail);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        currentFolder = getString(R.string.inbox);
        currentUser = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_EMAIL");
        setActionBarMail(currentFolder, currentUser);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);


        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));

        actionModeCallback = new ActionModeCallback();

        // show loader and fetch messages
        swipeRefreshLayout.post(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        getAllMails(15);
                    }
                }
        );
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_search) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void processResponse(OutlookObjectCall outlookObjectCall, JSONObject response) {

        switch (outlookObjectCall) {
            case READUSER: {
                System.out.println("reading user");
            } break;
            case READMAIL: {
                messages.clear();

                JSONObject list = response;
                try {
                    JSONArray mails = list.getJSONArray("value");
                    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Message>>() {
                    }.getType();
                    messages = new Gson().fromJson(String.valueOf(mails), listType);
                    for (Message message : messages) {
                        message.setColor(getRandomMaterialColor("400"));
                    }
                    System.out.println(messages.get(2).getFrom().getEmailAddress().getName());

                    mAdapter = new MessagesAdapter(this, messages, this);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            }
            break;
            case SENDMAIL: {
                System.out.println("Just send a mail." );
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        // swipe refresh is performed, fetch the messages again
        getAllMails(15);
    }

    @Override
    public void onIconClicked(int position) {
        if (actionMode == null) {
            actionMode = startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallback);
        }

        toggleSelection(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onIconImportantClicked(int position) {
        // Star icon is clicked,
        // mark the message as important
        Message message = messages.get(position);
        message.setImportance("normal");
        messages.set(position, message);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageRowClicked(int position) {
        // verify whether action mode is enabled or not
        // if enabled, change the row state to activated
        if (mAdapter.getSelectedItemCount() > 0) {
            enableActionMode(position);
        } else {
            // read the message which removes bold from the row
            Message message = messages.get(position);
            message.setIsRead("true");
            messages.set(position, message);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Read: " + message.getBodyPreview(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRowLongClicked(int position) {
        // long press is performed, enable action mode
        enableActionMode(position);
    }

    private void enableActionMode(int position) {
        if (actionMode == null) {
            actionMode = startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallback);
        }
        toggleSelection(position);
    }

    private void toggleSelection(int position) {
        mAdapter.toggleSelection(position);
        int count = mAdapter.getSelectedItemCount();

        if (count == 0) {
            actionMode.finish();
        } else {
            actionMode.setTitle(String.valueOf(count));
            actionMode.invalidate();
        }
    }


    private class ActionModeCallback implements ActionMode.Callback {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_action_mode, menu);

            // disable swipe refresh if action mode is enabled
            swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_delete:
                    // delete all the selected messages
                    deleteMessages();
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;

                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            mAdapter.clearSelections();
            swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
            actionMode = null;
            recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mAdapter.resetAnimationIndex();
                    // mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // deleting the messages from recycler view
    private void deleteMessages() {
        mAdapter.resetAnimationIndex();
        List<Integer> selectedItemPositions =
                mAdapter.getSelectedItems();
        for (int i = selectedItemPositions.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            mAdapter.removeData(selectedItemPositions.get(i));
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private void setActionBarMail(String title, String subtitle) {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
        getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle(subtitle);
    }

    private void getAllMails(int aantalMails) {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        try {
            new GraphAPI().getRequest(OutlookObjectCall.READMAIL, this, "/inbox/messages?$top=" + aantalMails);

        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private int getRandomMaterialColor(String typeColor) {
        int returnColor = Color.GRAY;
        int arrayId = getResources().getIdentifier("mdcolor_" + typeColor, "array", getPackageName());

        if (arrayId != 0) {
            TypedArray colors = getResources().obtainTypedArray(arrayId);
            int index = (int) (Math.random() * colors.length());
            returnColor = colors.getColor(index, Color.GRAY);
            colors.recycle();
        }
        return returnColor;
    }
```

MessagesAdapter.java

```
public class MessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessagesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Message> messages;
    private MessageAdapterListener listener;
    private SparseBooleanArray selectedItems;

    // array used to perform multiple animation at once
    private SparseBooleanArray animationItemsIndex;
    private boolean reverseAllAnimations = false;

    // index is used to animate only the selected row
    // dirty fix, find a better solution
    private static int currentSelectedIndex = -1;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnLongClickListener {
        public TextView from, subject, message, iconText, timestamp;
        public ImageView iconImp, imgProfile, imgBijlage;
        public LinearLayout messageContainer;
        public RelativeLayout iconContainer, iconBack, iconFront;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            from = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.from);
            subject = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_primary);
            message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_secondary);
            iconText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_text);
            timestamp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.timestamp);
            iconBack = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_back);
            iconFront = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_front);
            iconImp = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_star);
            imgProfile = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_profile);
            messageContainer = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.message_container);
            iconContainer = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_container);
            imgBijlage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_attachement);
            view.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            listener.onRowLongClicked(getAdapterPosition());
            view.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS);
            return true;
        }
    }


    public MessagesAdapter(Context mContext, List<Message> messages, MessageAdapterListener listener) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.messages = messages;
        this.listener = listener;
        selectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();
        animationItemsIndex = new SparseBooleanArray();
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.message_list_row, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Message message = messages.get(position);

        // displaying text view data
        holder.from.setText(message.getFrom().getEmailAddress().getName());
        holder.subject.setText(message.getSubject());
        holder.message.setText(message.getBodyPreview());
        System.out.println("EMAIL: " + position + " HAS ATTACHEMENT: " + message.getHasAttachments());
        setBijlage(message, holder);
        try {
            setDate(message, holder);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // displaying the first letter of From in icon text
        holder.iconText.setText(message.getFrom().getEmailAddress().getName().substring(0, 1));

        // change the row state to activated
        holder.itemView.setActivated(selectedItems.get(position, false));

        // change the font style depending on message read status
        applyReadStatus(holder, message);

        // handle message star
        applyImportant(holder, message);

        // handle icon animation
        applyIconAnimation(holder, position);

        // display profile image
        applyProfilePicture(holder, message);

        // apply click events
        applyClickEvents(holder, position);
    }

    private void setDate(Message message, MyViewHolder holder) throws ParseException {
        String stringDate = message.getReceivedDateTime();
        String COMPARE_FORMAT = "yyyy/MM/dd";
        String OUTPUT_FORMAT_NOT_TODAY = "dd MMM";
        String JSON_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(COMPARE_FORMAT);
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(JSON_FORMAT);
        SimpleDateFormat defaultFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(OUTPUT_FORMAT_NOT_TODAY);

        //today date (check if today)
        Date today = new Date();
        String currentDate = dateFormat.format(today);
        //hours (if today
        Date date = formatter.parse(stringDate);
        formatter.applyPattern(COMPARE_FORMAT);
        String mailDate = formatter.format(date);
        //dd/month (if not today)


        boolean is24 = DateFormat.is24HourFormat(mContext);

        if (mailDate.equals(currentDate)) {
            if (is24) {
                SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                holder.timestamp.setText(outputFormat.format(date));
            } else {
                SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
                holder.timestamp.setText(outputFormat.format(date));
            }
        } else {
            holder.timestamp.setText(defaultFormat.format(date));
        }
    }

    private void setBijlage(Message message, MyViewHolder holder){
        //set bijlage
        if (message.getHasAttachments().toLowerCase().equals("true")){
            holder.imgBijlage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bijlage);
        }
    }

    private void applyClickEvents(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.iconContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onIconClicked(position);
            }
        });

        holder.iconImp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onIconImportantClicked(position);
            }
        });

        holder.messageContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listener.onMessageRowClicked(position);
            }
        });

        holder.messageContainer.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                listener.onRowLongClicked(position);
                view.performHapticFeedback(HapticFeedbackConstants.LONG_PRESS);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void applyProfilePicture(MyViewHolder holder, Message message) {
            holder.imgProfile.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_circle);
            holder.imgProfile.setColorFilter(message.getColor());
            holder.iconText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    private void applyIconAnimation(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (selectedItems.get(position, false)) {
            holder.iconFront.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            resetIconYAxis(holder.iconBack);
            holder.iconBack.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.iconBack.setAlpha(1);
            if (currentSelectedIndex == position) {
                FlipAnimator.flipView(mContext, holder.iconBack, holder.iconFront, true);
                resetCurrentIndex();
            }
        } else {
            holder.iconBack.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            resetIconYAxis(holder.iconFront);
            holder.iconFront.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.iconFront.setAlpha(1);
            if ((reverseAllAnimations && animationItemsIndex.get(position, false)) || currentSelectedIndex == position) {
                FlipAnimator.flipView(mContext, holder.iconBack, holder.iconFront, false);
                resetCurrentIndex();
            }
        }
    }

    // As the views will be reused, sometimes the icon appears as
    // flipped because older view is reused. Reset the Y-axis to 0
    private void resetIconYAxis(View view) {
        if (view.getRotationY() != 0) {
            view.setRotationY(0);
        }
    }

    public void resetAnimationIndex() {
        reverseAllAnimations = false;
        animationItemsIndex.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return messages.get(position).getAutoId();
    }

    private void applyImportant(MyViewHolder holder, Message message) {
        if (message.getImportance().toLowerCase().equals("high")) {
            holder.iconImp.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_star_black_24dp));
            holder.iconImp.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.icon_tint_selected));
        } else {
            holder.iconImp.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext, R.drawable.ic_star_border_black_24dp));
            holder.iconImp.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.icon_tint_normal));
        }
    }

    private void applyReadStatus(MyViewHolder holder, Message message) {
        if (message.getIsRead().toLowerCase().equals("true")) {
            holder.from.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
            holder.subject.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
            holder.from.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.subject));
            holder.subject.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.message));
        } else {
            holder.from.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.subject.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.from.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.from));
            holder.subject.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.subject));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    public void toggleSelection(int pos) {
        currentSelectedIndex = pos;
        if (selectedItems.get(pos, false)) {
            selectedItems.delete(pos);
            animationItemsIndex.delete(pos);
        } else {
            selectedItems.put(pos, true);
            animationItemsIndex.put(pos, true);
        }
        notifyItemChanged(pos);
    }

    public void clearSelections() {
        reverseAllAnimations = true;
        selectedItems.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getSelectedItemCount() {
        return selectedItems.size();
    }

    public List<Integer> getSelectedItems() {
        List<Integer> items =
                new ArrayList<>(selectedItems.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
            items.add(selectedItems.keyAt(i));
        }
        return items;
    }

    public void removeData(int position) {
        messages.remove(position);
        resetCurrentIndex();
    }

    private void resetCurrentIndex() {
        currentSelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    public interface MessageAdapterListener {
        void onIconClicked(int position);

        void onIconImportantClicked(int position);

        void onMessageRowClicked(int position);

        void onRowLongClicked(int position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's occours because the recyclerView reuses the references of the rows and in your case, some rows doesnt have any reference in holder.imgBijlage, causing missbehavior.
To solve this, put `holder.imgBijlage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bijlage);` inside `onBindViewHolder` and change `setBijlage` to:

```
 if (message.getHasAttachments().toLowerCase().equals("true")){
        holder.imgBijlage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }else { 
        holder.imgBijlage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
 }
```

Your icon will be hidden when there is no attachement

Answer (score 3):

Change `setBijlage` to this..

```
private void setBijlage(Message message, MyViewHolder holder){
            //set bijlage
            if (message.getHasAttachments().toLowerCase().equals("true")){
                holder.imgBijlage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
                holder.imgBijlage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_bijlage);
            }else{
                holder.imgBijlage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
```